# Doubts in Proof of Pro. 7.3.3 in Andrew Pressley

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, proof-explanation

I was reading differential geometry form Andrew Pressley In that I had following doubt[image]

[image]

I understand everything except one thing why Weingarten map  $\omega (\gamma^.)=(\gamma^.)$

Form definition Weingarten map is just a negative of differential of Gauss map, where Gauss map gives normal .

Please Help me to understand above proposition

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: $\langle \mathcal W(\dot\gamma), \dot\gamma\rangle = \langle \dot\gamma, \dot\gamma\rangle$ does not require $\mathcal W(\dot\gamma) = \dot\gamma$, but only that $\mathcal W(\dot\gamma) - \dot\gamma$ is orthogonal to $\dot\gamma$. However, I'm not familiar with the Weingarten map, so I don't know if that helps explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressley has some garbage here. What you didn't tell us (perhaps because you don't remember it) is that Pressley must have *defined* $\langle u,v\rangle$ to be $\text{II}(u,v) = \mathcal W(u)\cdot v$. (This is confirmed by the second part of the proposition.) I don't own the book, and so I cannot check. However, there's a mistake since the equation should be
$$-\dot{\mathbf N}\cdot\dot\gamma = \mathcal W(\dot\gamma)\cdot\dot\gamma = \langle \dot\gamma,\dot\gamma \rangle,$$
having the usual dot product in the first spot.

By the way, $\mathcal W(\dot\gamma) = \lambda\dot\gamma$ if and only if $\gamma$ is a line of curvature (i.e., $\dot\gamma$ is an eigenvector of $\mathcal W$).